# I want a captcha for react like attached image

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-form

I use reactjs and redux-form for my website and I want some captcha like this image

[plz click here for see captcha image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BuO8r.png)

can anybody suggest good npm or yarn package for this work?

Comment: This https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-recaptcha might help.

Comment: this package only suggest google recaptcha
and i can not find recaptcha like attached image in google recaptcha site

can you help me how can i add "numeric captcha" to this package?

@Vebbie

Answer (score 0):

May be creating svg image in server side with node server can help you to create your own captcha in server side and show it in your react component without using googel api like this https://www.npmjs.com/package/svg-captcha

Comment: the down side of svg catcha is that it's svg (which is attempted to present as an advantage due to size). I think that having svg means that you can easily access the used font, download it, generate all the letters using it and feed the data to AI learning to by pass the captcha automatically. Some efforts - yes, but these efforts are way less than having no access to font in use. Probably better idea would be to find some filters to pass the svg and convert it to non vector image (png for example). And keep the font away from public. + use some graphic effects to whirpool/distort slightly.